# Inconsistency in the Spring Data Elasticsearch documentation for limiting the result size of query with Top or First keyword

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

Spring data offers a convenient way to limit results with the keyword Top or First.

We can read in the Spring Data ES documentation :

> The results of query methods can be limited via the keywords first or top, which can be used interchangeably.

Which means calling this method for instance :

> User findFirstByOrderByLastnameAsc();

Nonetheless, the list of supported keywords for Elasticsearch does not contain the keyword Top or First.

I ran several tests using the latest version of spring data elasticsearch and effectively, the Top and First keyword does not work.

Be aware of that.

[The Spring Data ES documentation Version 1.3.0.RELEASE,
2015-09-01](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/)